# Loop inside a loop with values in a .txt file

Tags: python

Here is my code :

```
filenames = []
data = []
found = False

axconfig = open('axcfgpasww.dat', "r")
dictionnary = open("hello.txt", "r")

output_value = "bonjour"
for line in axconfig:
    for word in dictionnary:
        element = word.split("=")[0]
        if element in axconfig:
            # old_value = line.split("=")
            # data.append(line.replace(old_value, output_value+'\n'))

            # found = True
        # else:
            # data.append(line)

            print(element)

if not found:
    print('No match found')

# Create a new file, from data array
with open("olivier.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    for line in data:
        outfile.write(line)
```

The dynamic value is "element".

I have a .txt file, that have keywords and want to look "element" with the values inside the .txt file.

But my code doesn't work..
It only adds in olivier.txt the first line of axcfgpasww.dat..
And is also returning "No match found"

Thanks guys !

edit :

> axcfgpasww.dat

```
T72_BANK_IDENTIFIER_CODE_3=SOAPFR22
T72_ISSUER_COUNTRY_CODE_3=FR
T72_MERCHANT_ID_3=
T72_VAS_SCHEME_IDENTIFIER_3=
```

> hello.txt

```
T72_VAS_SERVICE_IDENTIFIER_7=
T72_VAS_SCHEME_IDENTIFIER_3=
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what is stored in `dictionary` and `axconfig`?

Comment: Still can't understand your ask!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: I have edited my post, it should be clearer now no ?

Comment: "if element in axconfig:" I want that element takes the value of lines from hello.txt

Comment: U want "T72_VAS_SERVICE_IDENTIFIER_7" from hello.txt to be matched with every line of axcfgpasww.dat file. If it matches..do something.. right?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal exactly

Comment: @RahulAgarwal and also the second value "T72_VAS_SCHEME_IDENTIFIER_3="

Comment: No it didn't.. But I am trying another method to solve my problem$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the line:

`if element in axconfig:`

try instead:

`if element in line.split("=")`

Comment: it doesn't work. File "C:\count.py", line 14
    if element in line.split("=")
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

For my convenience if I have considered both as text files.

Below code will match each line of axconfig with hello and then print whatever is matched and also will store that value is a variable called "value"

```
filenames = []
data = []
found = False
value = ""
axconfig =  open('axcfgpasww.txt', "r")
lines = axconfig.readlines()
dictionnary = open("hello.txt", "r")

output_value = "bonjour"
for line in lines:
    match = line.split("=")[0]
    for word in dictionnary:
        element = word.split("=")[0]   
    if element == match:
        print(element)
        value = element
```

Comment: thanks for the help. But it doesn't work as expected

Comment: Where is it failing?